# flask error para instalarlo

Tags: python, flask

estoy intentando instalar el modulo flask y tengo este errror:

`py -m pip install flask`

```
ERROR: Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 180, in _main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\req_command.py", line 204, in wrapper
    return func(self, options, args)
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\install.py", line 318, in run
    requirement_set = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\resolver.py", line 127, in resolve
    result = self._result = resolver.resolve(
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 473, in resolve
    state = resolution.resolve(requirements, max_rounds=max_rounds)
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 341, in resolve
    name, crit = self._merge_into_criterion(r, parent=None)
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\resolvers.py", line 172, in _merge_into_criterion
    if not criterion.candidates:
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\resolvelib\structs.py", line 139, in __bool__
    return bool(self._sequence)
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 143, in __bool__
    return any(self)
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 129, in <genexpr>
    return (c for c in iterator if id(c) not in self._incompatible_ids)
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\found_candidates.py", line 30, in _iter_built
    for version, func in infos:
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\resolution\resolvelib\factory.py", line 258, in iter_index_candidate_infos
    result = self._finder.find_best_candidate(
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 879, in find_best_candidate
    candidates = self.find_all_candidates(project_name)
  File "C:\Alejandro\Alejandro\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\index\package_finder.py", line 824, in find_all_candidates
```

**Detalles**

- python 3.9
- windows 10

Este codigo me aparece en color rojo en la ventana de cmd
Aclaro que estoy empezando con python
agradezco su ayuda

Comment: Se instala con `pip install flask`

Comment: ya lo he probado y tampoco, sigo intentando y no puedo instalar ningun modulo siempre el mismo erro, que publique anteriormente, la version pip insyalada 21.1.1

Comment: Pero eso no parece un error al instalar, sino un error al ejecutar tu programa

Answer (score 0):

Usualmente los comandos para instalar alguna librería/módulo de [Pypi](https://pypi.org/) es pip o pip3 (este utilizo en Ubuntu20.04 y en otras distros GNU/Linux). Como dice en los comentarios, parece un error al ejecutar el programa y no un error de pip. Una solución podría ser reinstalar python y pip, y volver a ejecutar esos comandos. Para desintalarlo en Windows puedes ver esta [publicación](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3515673/how-to-completely-remove-python-from-a-windows-machine) y en caso de algún error, [esta](https://superuser.com/questions/1238473/cant-uninstall-python-3-6-on-windows-10).

Como recomendación general, a veces algunos errores al parecer muy difíciles de resolver pueden solucionarse con un simple reinicio o reinstalación, me ha servido mucho en le pasado y no complico tanto el problema.

Comment: gracias probare reinstalando y comento

Answer (score 0):

Usa pip install Flask, también te recomiendo guardar tu proyecto en un entorno virtual tipo venv en Linux o en un Iddle, dependiendo de cómo te guste trabajar. Ah, y asegúrate también de tener instalado pip en el directorio adecuado.